# pyjinius : android class not found

Tags: android, class, kivy, pyjnius

I am trying to use pyjinius to access android java services.
following the tutorial, and in some cases the android java class
is not found:

```
from jnius import autoclass

#this works
TextToSpeech = autoclass('android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech')

#this does not work!!!
CellSignal = autoclass('android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthGsm')
```

what should be done in order to access the latter class?
I am wondering what is the difference between the 2 cases,
they both seem standard android classes.
Should a .jar be added to the buildozer configuration file?
any idea of its name/location ?

marino

Comment: it is interesting to find out that my question has been downvoted, without any additional information. the downvoter obviously knows nothing about the subject, because the question is simple and obvious for somebody in this field of computer science.

Answer (score 0):

`android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthGsm` was added to Android in API level 17 (Jellybean 4.2). By default, buildozer targets API 14, so you will need to change `android.api` in your buildozer.spec to 17. You should also either set `android.minapi` to 17 as well, or perform runtime checks to ensure that you don't try to use that class if the device is running API <17.